# possible bottleneck in lambda function as the key in sort

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following code which enumerate the intersection of n lines, where the interested intersections are only at `x > 0` and for each intersection, I will maintain the order that at the right of intersection, the lines are ordered by their slope.

```
def enum_itsc(k, b):
    n = len(k)
    itsc_list = dict()
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(i + 1, n):
            x = (b[j] - b[i]) / (k[i] - k[j])
            y = x * k[i] + b[i]
            if x <= 0:
                continue

            if (x, y) in itsc_list:
                itsc_list[(x, y)].update([i, j])
            else:
                itsc_list[(x,y)] = set([i, j])

    for itsc in itsc_list:
        itsc_list[itsc] = list(itsc_list[itsc])
        itsc_list[itsc].sort(key=lambda i: k[i])

    return itsc_list
```

After a little profile, it seems there is significant cost on the `lambda` function. How should I improve the code? Or this is what it is and there is no way to improve.

Comment: `list.sort` will sort numbers without the need for a lambda

Comment: You don't need to pass any `key` function just to sort the list numerically, that is the default behavior.

Comment: Please include a complete program that others can run demonstrating your concern. Your English-language description will always be more ambiguous than code. For example, your description omits the definition of `k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use builtin functions as the `key` for `sort` where possible. In this case, `key=lambda i: k[i]` is equivalent to `key=k.__getitem__`

I did a small test with made-up values and saw approximately a 1.5-2x speedup from changing this. (On just the sort operation). Of course this may differ depending on your data.

Another good source of standard-library functions for `key` for future reference is the `operator` module (e.g. `operator.itemgetter`, `operator.attrgetter`...)

Comment: Indeed you're absolutely right. I am just evaluating the performance using your suggestion `__getitem__` and the sort operation is about 2x speedup. Thank you very much for the help!